# How to hide a Windowns Powershell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell

I'm currently running a Python script in PowerShell, and everything works fine. However, I'd like the PowerShell window to remain hidden during execution, possibly in the 'hidden icons' section or a similar setup. I attempted using a .ps1 shortcut, but it didn't work. I also sought assistance from ChatGPT, but the guidance was limited. Can you provide instructions on how to achieve this?